# How fast the height of the cone is changing?

Tags: calculus, geometry, derivatives, volume

Suppose that sand is collecting in the shape of a cone in such a way that the base radius of the cone is always one-third of its height. If $3\,\mathrm{cm^3/min}$ is the rate at which the sand is being added to the cone, how fast is the height of the cone changing when it is $7\,\mathrm{cm}$ tall?

I got $Dv/dt=3cm^3 $ and $r=1/3h$. So I'm looking for $dh/dt$ when $h=7$. I'm not sure if I'm doing the problem right.

Comment: What you have so far looks reasonable. Don't forget that $\frac{dV}{dt} = 3\text{cm}^3\text{/min}$, i.e., include the time part. Also, you should find & use the formula for the volume to be able to solve the problem.

Comment: @JohnOmielan So I got dv/dt = 1/9 πh^2 dh/dt. When I computed, I ended up with dh/dt = -22/9 cm/min. Would this be the correct answer?

Comment: You have the correct formula, but I don't know how you got $\frac{dh}{dt}$ to be $-\frac{22}{9}$ cm/min. Note that as sand is being added to the cone, the height must be increasing with time, so $\frac{dh}{dt}$ is a positive value. I provided the, I believe, correct value for it in my answer below.

Comment: @JohnOmielan I was a bit confused getting a negative number as my answer. I've realized my mistake in my computation. I actually subtracted 49π/9 from both sides getting -22π/9 as my answer. The last step of my computation was wrong. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. It's usually a good idea to not only double-check your work, but also ask if the answer seems reasonable or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Wolfgang Kais](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/640973/wolfgang-kais) states in his answer, the formula for the volume of a cone is

$$V = \pi r^2 \cfrac{h}{3} \tag{1}\label{eq1}$$

As the question, and OP, states, the radius is always one-third the height, so $r = \frac{h}{3}$. Thus, \eqref{eq1} becomes

$$V = \pi \cfrac{h^3}{27} \tag{2}\label{eq2}$$

Differentiating with respect to $t$ gives

$$\cfrac{dV}{dt} = \pi \cfrac{h^2}{9} \cfrac{dh}{dt} \tag{3}\label{eq3}$$

This is what the OP has already determined, and states in a comment. Now, it's given that $\frac{dV}{dt} = 3\text{ cm}^3$/min and it asks for $\frac{dh}{dt}$ when $h = 7$ cm. Plugging these values into \eqref{eq3} gives

$$3 = \pi \cfrac{49}{9} \cfrac{dh}{dt} \Rightarrow \cfrac{dh}{dt} = \cfrac{27}{49\pi}  \tag{4}\label{eq4}$$

Thus, the height at $7$ cm is increasing at a rate of $\frac{27}{49\pi}$ cm/min.

Answer (score 0):

If you were a physicist, you would express $h$ as a function of $V$, expand the fraction $\frac{dh}{dt}$ by multiplying it with $1=\frac{dV}{dV}$, find that $\frac{dh}{dt}=\frac{dh}{dt}\frac{dV}{dV}=\frac{dh}{dV}\frac{dV}{dt}$ (the "chain rule") and only need the deviation $\frac{dh}{dV}$ (because you already have $\frac{dV}{dt}$).

Hint: $V=\pi r^2\cdot\frac13h=\pi\left(\frac13h\right)^3$, so $h = 3\left(\frac{V}{\pi}\right)^{1/3}$, and if $h=7$ then $V=\pi\left(\frac73\right)^3$.

**Added:**

As seen in the comments, it seems to be unclear how to continue with these hints, so here's how to move on from there:

We have: $h=3\left(\frac{V}{\pi}\right)^{1/3}$ and thus $\frac{dh}{dV}=\frac{1}{\pi}\left(\frac{V}{\pi}\right)^{-2/3}$

Also, we know from the prerequisites: $\frac{dV}{dt} = 3\,\mathrm{cm^3/min}$.

As deduced, before, $\frac{dh}{dt}=\frac{dh}{dV}\frac{dV}{dt}$ of which we now know both factors and can calculate:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{dh}{dt} & =\frac{dh}{dV}\cdot\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{1}{\pi}\left(\frac{V}{\pi}\right)^{-2/3}\cdot\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{1}{\pi}\left(\left(\frac{h}{3}\right)^3\right)^{-2/3}\cdot\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{9}{\pi h^2}\cdot3\,\mathrm{\frac{cm^3}{min}}\\
& =\frac{27}{\pi h^2}\,\mathrm{\frac{cm^3}{min}}
\end{align}
$$
Now, we can evaluate this for the given height $h=7\,\mathrm{cm}$ and finally get an increase rate of

$$
\frac{27}{\pi h^2}\,\mathrm{\frac{cm^3}{min}}=\frac{27}{\pi\cdot 49\,\mathrm{cm^2}}\,\mathrm{\frac{cm^3}{min}}=\frac{27}{49\pi}\,\mathrm{\frac{cm}{min}}
$$

Comment: The question asks for the rate of the height changing, not the volume. I don't see how knowing what the specific volume is at that time helps to answer the question.

Comment: @JohnOmielan, the value of the volume was just a *hint* so to know what value to insert in the deviation $ \frac{dh}{dV} = \frac{1}{\pi} \left( \frac{V}{\pi} \right)^{-2/3}$.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, as the question wants to know how "fast" the height is increasing, the implicit assumption is that it's with respect to time, not the volume, so I believe calculating $\frac{dh}{dV}$ will likely get the wrong numeric result, not to mention in the incorrect units.

Comment: Dear John, I did not intend to do the whole calculation and $\frac{dh}{dV}$ is not the final result. As I stated in my answer, $\frac{dh}{dt}=\frac{dh}{dV}\frac{dV}{dt}$. Of these two factors, $\frac{dV}{dt}$ is already known, and $\frac{dh}{dV}$ can be calculated with the formula from above: $\frac{dh}{dV}=\frac{1}{\pi}\left(\frac{V}{\pi}\right)^{-2/3}$. But of course you are right, I should consider the correct Units. I added the remaining calculation to my answer, including the correct units. :-)

Comment: Once again, thanks for the extra explanation. On rereading your original answer, I now see what you were getting at. It seems to be a more roundabout method, but as you have explained in the comments and in the answer update, it is valid.